# Neovim do not work on mac

Tags: macos, vim, neovim

I installed neovim v0.2.2 via homebrew:

```
$ brew install neovim
$ alias n="nvim -u $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim"
```

Then, neovim causes many errors, so I cannot use it.

1. First, when I open a file, say `n foo.rb`, the filetype is not detected: `:set ft?` gives `filetype=`.
2. Second, I tried `:CheckHealth`, but it is said `Not an editor command: CheckHealth`. I also tried `:checkhealth`, giving `Invalid 'runtimepath'`. So I checked `:set rtp?`, but it seems to be right.
3. Third, when I entered insert mode, deoplete raised an error `Unknown function js_encode`.
4. Finally, I could not copy texts to clipboard `"+y`.

I think there must be more errors I have not found.

I checked `:set rtp?`, but it is OK. And all key mappings `[nvics][nore]map` work correctly, so `init.vim` is certainly loaded.

These errors occur only after updating neovim from v0.2.0 to v0.2.2. They do not occur when I used v0.2.0.

Environments:

- mac OS 10.12.6
- neovim v0.2.2

Comment: What's the value of `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`?

Comment: `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set to be `~/.config`, and `init.vim` is in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim`.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong with Oni. I `rm` all files concerning oni, `:call dein#update()`, and `:UpdateRemotePlugins`, then Neovim recovered.